# How do I automatically generate colour styles in LibreOffice Calc using VBA?

Tags: vba, macros, libreoffice-calc, styles, cell-format

I want to be able to run a macro to automatically create a set of named styles that change the cell background colour.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```vb
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub CreateColorStyles()
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oCellStyles As Object
    Dim r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sVBA As String

    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oCellStyles = oDoc.StyleFamilies.getByName("CellStyles")
    'oStyle = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.style.CellStyle")
    
    For r = 0 To 255
        For g = 0 To 255
            For b = 0 To 255
                sName =  r & "-" & g & "-" & b
                sVBA = "oRGB-" & sName & " = oDoc.createInstance(" & """" & "com.sun.star.style.CellStyle" & """" & ")"
                oStyle = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.style.CellStyle")
                oStyle.Name = "oRGB-" & sName
                oStyle.CellBackColor = RGB(r, g, b)
                oCellStyles.insertByName(oStyle.Name, oStyle)
            Next b
        Next g
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you get the wrong colour? The wrong cells are changed? An error occurs? Have you tried adding a breakpoint to see if the variables are being set correctly?

Comment: Can I ask you to give up this idea? Firstly, this is a pointless waste of resources. Are you going to create 16777216 different styles? That's 16 times more than count rows there are in a sheet. Running such a macro will take many hours, the document in which all these styles will be saved will be gigantic in size, and loading and saving it will take a long, long time. Secondly, no one can visually distinguish the color #0FDF02 from the color #0FDF10 - so why create one? Please don't try to create them all.

Comment: @spikey_richie No, the code fails. No styles are created as far as I can tell.

Comment: @JohnSUN Hahaha! I missed the maths...yeah, that is a silly idea to create that many. The only reason I was trying to do it was because there does not seem to be a way to dynamically set the cell background colour based upon a function. If I were able to do this, then I could have called them up using the STYLE function...but, you spotted a school-boy error on my part....I don't suppose you do have any ideas as to how to dynamically set the cell colour? The problem with Conditional formatting is that you can't really do it dynamically as it too relies on predefined styles.

Comment: Doesn't such a method exist? Yes, you are right - now I have no ideas on this topic, I implemented them all five years ago and successfully forgot about them. Look [**here**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/in-calc-is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-fill-a-cell-with-a-color-based-on-a-hex-code-rgb-values-lo-color-code-in-an-adjacent-cell/38191/4) for example

Comment: Thanks @JohnSUN, your example linked in your comment is a great method.